# Calcular expressão em um único campo input Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estou desenvolvendo uma calculadora em *HTML* + *JQuery* aonde tenho as operações básicas para a mesma, porém preciso implementar o seguinte:

Quando o usuário digitar no campo *input* uma expressão tipo: **(5*5)+4** o *JQuery* teria de pegar este valor realizar a operação e mostrar o resultado. alguma ideia de como poderia estar fazendo isto ?

```
$("input[name=exp]").click(function(){
    valor = $("#result").val();
    $("#result").val(valor);
});
```

**segue meu código JQuery :**

```
$( function(){

    var v1, v2, op;

    $("input[name=btn]").click(function(){
        $("#result").val($("#result").val() + $(this).val());
    });

    $("input[name=ce]").click(function(){
        $("#result").val('');
        $("#op").text('');
    });

    $("input[name=soma]").click(function(){
        if($("#result").val() != ''){
            v1 = parseFloat($("#result").val());
            $("#result").val('');
            op = "soma";
            $("#op").text($(this).val());
        }else{
            alert("Insira um valor para efetuar a operação");
        }
    });

    $("input[name=menos]").click(function(){
        if($("#result").val() != ''){
            v1 = parseFloat($("#result").val());
            $("#result").val('');
            op = "menos";
            $("#op").text($(this).val());
        }else{
            alert("Insira um valor para efetuar a operação");
        }
    });

    $("input[name=vezes]").click(function(){
        if($("#result").val() != ''){
            v1 = parseFloat($("#result").val());
            $("#result").val('');
            op = "vezes";
            $("#op").text($(this).val());
        }else{
            alert("Insira um valor para efetuar a operação");
        }
    });

    $("input[name=divisao]").click(function(){
        if($("#result").val() != ''){
            v1 = parseFloat($("#result").val());
            $("#result").val('');
            op = "divisao";
            $("#op").text($(this).val());
        }else{
            alert("Insira um valor para efetuar a operação");
        }
    });

    $("input[name=igual]").click(function(){
        if($("#result").val() != ''){
            v2 = parseFloat($("#result").val());

            if(op == "soma"){
                $("#result").val(v1 + v2);
            }else if(op == "menos"){
                $("#result").val(v1 - v2);
            }else if(op == "vezes"){
                $("#result").val(v1 * v2);
            }else{
                $("#result").val(v1 / v2);
            }
        }else{
            alert("Insira um valor para efetuar a operação");
        }
    });

    $("input[name=apagar").click(function(){
        var len = $("#result").val().length;

        var valor = $("#result").val();
        valor = valor.replace(valor.charAt(len - 1), "");
        $("#result").val(valor);
    });

});
```

Comment: Olha, é mais pratico colocar toda operação dentro de um único input e usar a função `eval()` para fazer o calculo: `eval("(5*5)+4")` resulta 29. Os botões seriam apenas para inserir os sinais

Comment: Eu não posso utilizar a função eval. tenho de realizar a operação sem. mais obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: Então eu acho que só com regular expressão, o problema é que eu não entendo muito disso.

Comment: Encontrei a solução [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49099008/calculate-expression-in-a-single-field-jquery/49113706#49113706[/link]